# Concept of Universe in the Old Testament

Tags: science

In the Old Testament, many verses report the beliefs about the structure of the Universe.
Surprisingly (well... for me!), these believes seem not to change much from the very early books to the latest ones.

All of them speak about "waters", "abysses", "circles" and so on.

Here are some examples:

> He marks out the horizon on the face of the waters for a boundary between light and darkness (Job 26:10)

> When he prepared the heavens, I was there: when he set a compass upon the face of the depth: When he established the clouds above: when he strengthened the fountains of the deep: When he gave to the sea his decree, that the waters should not pass his commandment: when he appointed the foundations of the earth (Proverbs 8:27-29)

> from sea to sea (Psalm 72:8, Zech. 9:10)

> Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters (Genesis 1-2)

So, waters seem to be a primordial material out of which the ordered world was created.

It's not clear to me if terms like "circle" are used to indicate a real representation of the Earth, or a "perfect shape" (a sphere) or other.

How was the universe structured?
Can a representation be provided?

**UPDATE**

As @dottard pointed out in a comment, "There was little or not concept of "universe" in the OT". This is certainly true, if we consider "Universe" as we do nowadays. My question addresses the concept of "universe" as the "set of all existing matter and space, considered as a whole", instead. (I hope this update clarifies my question a bit)

Comment: There was little or not concept of "universe" in the OT - there was simply (1) arable, water and seas land with (2) sky/heavens above containing clouds, stars, sun & moon and the above of spirits (good and bad) and God.  That's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, Hebrew understanding of the universe was more like cosmological beliefs. Here are some key elements of the ancient Hebrew cosmology that I think stand out:

[image]

[Primordial Waters/Primeval Sea:](https://stillpoint.substack.com/p/the-primeval-seagod-rules-the-chaotic#:%7E:text=The%20%E2%80%9Cprimeval%20sea%E2%80%9D%20is%20the,first%20chapter%20of%20Genesis%20unfolds.)

> The “primeval sea” is the uncreated state, **the chaos that preceded
> God’s ordering of creation.** These are **the waters of uncreation** where
> no life can flourish, no meanings can take root, no order can take
> shape. It is the opposite of the good place God is about to bring
> about as the first chapter of Genesis unfolds.

> **Deep (Tehom)**: The deep sea, the primeval ocean, the “waters below”.
> Also, the abyss or the grave. The deep is the place of Job’s leviathan
> and the word for the waters of death that sweep in over Pharaoh's
> armies after the Hebrews have safely crossed the Red Sea (yam suph,
> the sea of reeds).

Genesis 1:2 New King James Version

> 2 The earth was **without form, and void**; and darkness was on the
> face of the deep. And the Spirit of God was **hovering over the face of
> the waters.**

[Heaven and Earth:](https://stillpoint.substack.com/p/the-primeval-seagod-rules-the-chaotic#:%7E:text=The%20%E2%80%9Cprimeval%20sea%E2%80%9D%20is%20the,first%20chapter%20of%20Genesis%20unfolds.)

> Heavens (Shamayim): The visible universe above the earth and the
> invisible abode of God. The place of the “waters above.”
>
> Earth (erets): Land itself, the whole earth, in particular, the land
> of Canaan, the promised land.

[Firmament/Dome/Vaulted Sky](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/ngier/gre13.htm)

> The most striking feature of the Old Testament world is the
> "**firmament**," **a solid dome which separates "the waters from the waters"**
> (Gen. 1:6). The Hebrew word translated in the Latin Vulgate as
> firmamentum is raqia' whose verb form means "to spread, stamp or beat
> out." The material beaten out is not directly specified, but both
> biblical and extrabiblical evidence suggests that it is metal. A verb
> form of raqia' is used in both of these passages: "And gold leaf was
> hammered out..." (Ex. 39:3); and "beaten silver is brought from
> Tarshish" (Jer. l0:9). There are indeed figurative uses of this term.
> A firmament is part of the first vision of Ezekiel (1:22,26), and the
> editors of the evangelical Theological Wordbook of the Old Testament
> cite this as evidence that the Hebrews did not believe in a literal
> sky-dome. It is clear, however, that Ezekiel's throne chariot is the
> cosmos in miniature, and the use of raqia' **most likely refers to a
> solid canopy (it shines "like crystal") than to a limited space.**(6)
>
> The idea of the **dome or vault of heaven** is found in many Old Testament books, > e.g., "God founds his vault upon the earth..." (Amos
> 9:6). The Hebrew word translated as "vault" is 'aguddah whose verb
> form means to "bind, fit, or construct." Commenting on this verse,
> Richard S. Cripps states that "here it seems that the 'heavens' are
> 'bound' or fitted into a solid vault, the ends of which are upon the
> earth." We have seen that raqia' and 'aguddah, whose referent is
> obviously the same, mean something very different from the empty
> spatial expanse that some evangelicals suggest.

[Foundations of the Earth:](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/ngier/gre13.htm)

The earth was thought to be supported or founded upon pillars or foundations (e.g., 1 Samuel 2:8, Job 9:6), which upheld the landmasses and kept the earth stable.

> If we disengage ourselves from our own world-view, we can appreciate
> the internal logic of the Hebrew cosmology. If we are threatened by
> watery chaos from all sides, then **a solid sky would be needed to hold
> back these ominous seas**. **If the sky is a solid dome, then it will need
> pillars to support it.** Furthermore, **if the earth is a flat disc
> floating on "the deep," then it would make sense for it to have some
> support to hold it in place.** One finds the idea of physical supports
> for heaven in most ancient mythology. One Vedic poet writes of a god
> "by whom the awesome sky and earth were made firm, by whom the dome of
> the sky was propped up"; and Varuna "pillared both the worlds apart as
> the unborn supported heaven" (Rig-veda 10.121.5; 8.41.10).

Waters Above and Below:

[image]

<sup>Martin Luther’s 1534 German Bible depicted his view of the ‘waters above’ as a ‘cosmic shell’ of liquid water surrounding the entire (geocentric) universe.</sup>

Some passages speak of the existence of "waters above" the firmament, separated from the waters below (Genesis 1:6-8, Psalm 148:4). **Today, this is often thought to be the division between the waters of the sky (clouds, rain) and the waters of the earth (seas, rivers).**

From [creation.com](https://creation.com/waters-above-survey):

> In Genesis 1:6–8, God created an ‘expanse’ (Hebrew: raqiya רָקִיעַ)
> that **separated the waters of the deep (verse 2) into two parts—the
> waters “under the expanse” and those “above the expanse”.** While the
> waters below became seas, opinion is divided on the nature of the
> waters above.

> Four most common views of the ‘expanse/firmament’ (raqiya) and the
> ‘waters above’ seem to be the following:
>
> 1. **Heavenly Sea:** According to this view, the biblical writers accepted
>    the cosmological views of their ancient neighbours who (supposedly)
>    believed in a flat earth and a solid sky which held back a liquid
>    ocean above. **So, the raqiya refers not to a spacious expanse, but to a
>    solid dome resting on the earth, and the ‘waters above’ are a sky
>    ocean.**
> 2. **Pre-Flood Canopy:** This view says the raqiya is the atmosphere and **the ‘waters above’ are a water-vapour (or ice) canopy that surrounded
>    the pre-Flood Earth**
> 3. **Cosmic Shell:**... **that the waters are beyond all the galaxies, surrounding the universe perhaps as a tenuous shell of ice
>    particles.** The raqiya is understood to include all of interstellar
>    space.
> 4. **Clouds:**

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt at a pictorial representation of what is described in Genesis.

[image]

Comment: Not very biblical.

Comment: If you do the work of mapping the drawing to the Genesis account - as Jason did - it is biblical.